# Returning row from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm a newb to the whole PHP, jQuery (Ajax), Mysql stack, and I can't figure this out.

I have some PHP code making a call to Mysql and returning one row, in that same page I read the json being returned from php into jquery and I use the `JSON.parse` function and I can retrieve the information in that object like this: `client.firstname`, `client.lastname` and so on.

PHP:

```
        $query="SELECT * FROM clients WHERE  clientid='$clientid'";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
        $num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);         
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $client=json_encode($row);
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    data='<?php echo $client?>';
    client=JSON.parse(data);
    $("#company").val(client.company);
    $("#firstname").val(client.firstname);
});
```

However my problem begins when I try to make an ajax call to a PHP file which executes the same query, and returns the same data. Once I receive the json object on the ajax call I can print it out and see I am receiving the row back, but as soon as I call the `JSON.parse(data)` function I get an error message

PHP:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM clients WHERE  clientid='$clientid'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);         
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$client=json_encode($row);
echo $client; //this is the only different line
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ClientDetails.php",
    data: "clientid="clientid,
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data){
        client=JSON.parse(data);
        $("#company").val(client.company);
        $("#firstname").val(client.firstname);
    }
});
```

Once I run it I get this error message in Firebug:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does `<?php echo $client?>` output exactly? Also you forgot the semicolon at the end of it. `<?php echo $client; ?>`

Comment: is that the contents of ClientDetails.php you posted there  or is ClientDetails.php a separate php document?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to parse it, jQuery does that for you since you specified the dataType.

```
success: function(client){
    //client=JSON.parse(data);
    $("#company").val(client.company);
```

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the insights to all of you, I was doing something very stupid, I had my html standard document tags in my PHP file, got rid of all the tags and that got rid of the "JSON.parse: unexpected character" error message.

However I still could not see anything being printed when I did       
       $("#company").val(client.company);
I tried creating a complete new ajax calling page and it worked, something must have been in cache I think.

Thanks all.